# Button Id not resolved

Tags: java, android, button

My java component states that there is an unknown class but I clearly stated the new id in my xml file

content_user_response.xml

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/gotomoodanalysis"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

UserResponse.java

```
package com.example.enxin.emotiontracker;

import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class UserResponse extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button gotomoodanalysis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_response);
    }

    gotomoodanalysis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next1);

}
```

I need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the error log.

Comment: What does `activity_user_response.xml` look like?

Comment: i am sorry to say but what is this?? is this really a question,  i have seen many difficult questions getting heavily down voted but this question is getting answer coz it is easy...? really something wrong with people these days......

Comment: @theblindprophet do u really need log cat to find error in this snippet?? :o

Comment: A question needs to provide all supplemental information. Describing the error could result in a much different interpretation then actually providing the error itself.

Comment: but in this case error is clear and can be found at a glance....

Comment: Your banter is pointless. SO allows the opportunity of all users to answer questions and not only those experienced in the tagged language. The question may be "obvious" to some, but not to others looking to answer the question.

Comment: Dont get angry @theblindprophet, buddy :) have a look at those questions which are completely legit but still get down votes because cool thinking high school kiddos cant answer them so they down vote them... under that contrast this Question is by no means a question, every tutorial on planet earth of Android development teaches to initialize views inside onCreate... well peace.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be **inside** `onCreate`, because view is inflated when `setContentView` is called:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_response);

    gotomoodanalysis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gotomoodanalysis);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.enxin.emotiontracker;

import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class UserResponse extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button gotomoodanalysis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_response);
        gotomoodanalysis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gotomoodanalysis);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**void setContentView (View view)**

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed
>   directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a
>   complex view hierarchy. When calling this method, the layout
>   parameters of the specified view are ignored.

Android **void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)** Called when the activity is starting .

**`void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`** is where most initialization should go .

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_response);
    gotomoodanalysis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gotomoodanalysis); //  You should initialize in here
}
```

You should read official guide line

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html